# VS Code, React project, intellisense when using absolute import paths

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

In my react project when I use in:

```
//package.json
"name": "app"
```

then intellisense is not working for absolute path imports

```
//SomeComponent.js
import {StorageKeys} from 'app/Constants' // inellisense don't work
import {StorageKeys} from '../../Constants' // intellisense works
```

Tried some suggestions regarding "jsconfig.json" and setting compiler's base url but with no success.
Any Idea?

Answer (score -2):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES6",
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "paths" : {
        "app/*" : ["./*"]
      }
  },
  "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what exactly you did to fix the problem?